# ModelMultipleChoiceField is not working with UUID as primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a scenario where I have a field that is hidden....and when this field is a normal PK as generated by Postgresql all is well.  When I change said PK to a UUID instead...not so much.  When the field is defined as a normal PK the form submits fine.  When it's a UUID...I get SELECT A VALID CHOICE.......

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['book'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),  
                                queryset=Author.objects.filter(author=user).exclude(Q(is_active="False")),required=False)
```

The above works fine if Author PK is a normal PK.  When it's a UUID...that's when it won't submit.
I've read about this and it would appear that you have to override the selections somehow as a possible answer..so I tried...

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['book'] = [c.pk for c in Author.object.filter(author=user)]
```

But it still gives me that same error...SELECT A VALID CHOICE.....

Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you share your models, views and rest of your form?

Comment: @IainShelvington  I figured it out.  I was testing and took a shortcut that caused this error.  This works as I've laid it out if you take the proper steps and don't shortcut on your testing :).  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I appreciate it.  Merry Christmas!